# Difference between private endpoint and microsoft routing in azure storage account

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-vpn

I am trying to understand that to make storage account secure from the perspective of file upload and download via SAS URL is Microsoft routing and private endpoint both required or they solve the same purpose or we can prefer one over the other

From the documentation it seems they both use Microsoft network.

Please help me understand this topic.

Comment: What is your use case ? From where or how are you going to upload files to your storage account - via mobile client app or apps running on-prem? Private endpoint to your blob storage account ensures only clients from your VNet can access your storage. So, if your use case is for mobile app to do file upload, then `private endpoint` doesn't suit you.

Comment: For me everything will be within VPN , even the SAS URL generated will be used by any client within same VPN

Answer (score 0):

I think SAS and Private Link are two different security mechanisms.

SAS is like a shared secret or password. Anyone who holds it can access your service. Your service endpoint is always exposed on the public Internet.

A private link is like a VPN. Your service is not accessible via the Public Internet but only through the private link you have set up. Users must be inside your VNet or from a paired VNet. In addition, a [cost](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/private-link/#overview) is involved in using the private link.

You are correct that Azure services run on the Microsoft network backbone, so the network speed is not a concern.

Comment: There is also service endpoint if the client is running on VNet. OP did not mention about the client but I would check if it is trusted Azure service and MSI can do both: firewall and auth